# Is it possible to track files inside a submodule?

Tags: git

I want to save one of *my* files inside a submodule which I can't commit to.  How can I do this?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
$ tree my-repo/
my-repo/
├── bar
├── foo
└── not-my-repo
    └── my-file
```

In this example, I have commit privilege to `my-repo` but not `not-my-repo`.  But I want to put a file `my-file` inside of `not-my-repo` and have it still tracked in `my-repo`.  Is this possible using submodules?  The point of this is to still be able to `git pull` updates from `not-my-repo`'s remote, while not overwriting `my-file` every time.

Comment: No, this is not possible. But you could fork `not-my-repo` and commit it there.

Comment: Apart from what @MrTux correctly suggested, I want to add that nothing stops you from having two remotes. One is yours, and another one for pulling changes from upstream.

Comment: ah well. Thanks both of you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+file+inside+submodule

Comment: Thanks for the quick help finding the duplicate everyone.  Sometimes when searching a question, and finding a bunch of 0-vote questions/answers, I just don't bother digging in to see if my question is answered among them.  Next time I'll give those results more of a chance.